# how do I launch a google slides document in slideshow mode

Tags: google-chrome

On a kiosk, I want to launch a Google Slides document in slideshow mode, not in the edit mode. I can get the document to launch from CMD by entering "start chrome "https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1CHqV_m92A0FpmoSXSQYZvXH0xktSvusDgbTDkkHUJGc", however it starts in the editor. I want it to start the slideshow upon launch.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first publish the Google slides document. Then you can copy the published link and use that to access the presentation.